# What is the Mac 256-color system palette?

Tags: mac, icon, color, resources

I have some old Mac files, of which I want to extract and display their icons. To do this, I will decode their icl8 resources. According to Inside Macintosh, icl8 resources do not include a color table--instead, they are drawn according to the system palette. The problem is, nobody seems to have ever extracted and made the palette available online. All I can find is a basic description on Wikipedia.

What are the color values of the Macintosh 256-color system palette?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://belkadan.com/blog/2018/01/Color-Palette-8/.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Mac system color palettes are typically stored as "clut" resources in the ROM. There are palettes for 8-, 4-, 2- and 1-bit depths.

Belkadan Software has helpfully provided the 8-bit palette here: http://belkadan.com/blog/2018/01/Color-Palette-8/